# Making a firebase query search NOT case sensitive

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanna pull information from a Firebase Database but it's a case sensitive query, and i don't want it to be case sensitive, is there a way to make the query NOT case sensitive in Android Studio ,**Here is the query code**

```
DatabaseReference SearchRef = (DatabaseReference) FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Child1").orderByChild("Child2").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff"); // \uf8ff is a white space
    Query Searchquery = Searchref;
    Searchquery.addValueEventListener...
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When using `Firebase Database`, that is the much you get to from `orderByChild()` function. It returns data either ascending or descending order and you cannot customize your result with extended queries.

However, You can try a something else that may be a bit more expensive. 
Get all the children you want as an array, saving Child2 and its key. You can then change the string to upper case or lower case and access the desired result using the key.

The reference result would be

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Child1").child(key);
```

**EDIT**

To add on your logic, If you want "Dave" or "dave" to return Dave and dave
You can edit your query to `startAt(text.toUppercase)` and `endAt(text.toLowerCase+ "\uf8ff")`. This will return DAVE, Dave, dave etc

Comment: Great answer, but the query search depends on something a user puts in ie an edit text, and i want the query search to return Child2 without having to worry about case sensitivity at all, let's say there are 3 child2 strings in the database, the first is "Dave" the second one is "dave" and the third is "Sam", if the user searches for "D" the query will only return "Dave", i want it to return "dave" too

Comment: Oh, I get you more. Am editing the answer

Comment: Quick question, the `startAt(text.toUppercase)` will it return values with spaces too or  do i have to add `"+ \uf8ff"`

Comment: It wil return anything starting with that name. eg "Dave stone". Note this is not the official way to search in Firebase and it is better to use Firestore.

Comment: Ah, i understand, Thanks your answer is amazing , and yes i know but i'v structured my whole application on firebase database, and changing now will take a lot of time, which i don't have much of

Comment: If I don't miss anything, then if you search between D and d + "\uf8ff", you get Dave and dave, but you also get everything starting with E, F, G,  ..., Z, a, b, c...

Comment: Experiencing the same thing^

Comment: Another way would be to store a lowercase copy of child2 in child3 at the time of saving the object in database and then always convert your EditText query to lowercase and always query child3 instead of child2.

Comment: cant believe firebase hasnt thought of this