# angularfire5 & firebase autocomplete equivelent to WHERE LIKE?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, angularfire5

My autocomplete services for firebase using angularfire2 v5 look like this:

```
getUsersTypeAhead(searchString: string) {
    const list: AngularFireList<User> = this.fireBase.list('/users', ref => ref
        .orderByChild('name')
        .limitToFirst(10)
        .startAt(searchString)
        .endAt(searchString + '\uf8ff')
    );
    return list.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(items => items.map(item => ({
            key: item.key,
            name: item.payload.val().name
        })))
    );
}
```

However this appears to be case sensitive. Is this a limitation or is there a query that would be similar to WHERE LIKE in mySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this answer here [Making a firebase query search NOT case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812056/making-a-firebase-query-search-not-case-sensitive)

```
getUsersTypeAhead(searchString: string) {
    const list: AngularFireList<User> = this.fireBase.list('/users', ref => ref
        .orderByChild('name')
        .limitToFirst(5)
        .startAt(searchString.toUpperCase())
        .endAt(searchString.toLowerCase() + '\uf8ff')
    );
    return list.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(items => items.map(item => ({
            key: item.key,
            name: item.payload.val().name
        })))
    );
}
```