# How to get all documents from collection according to specific field from Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have this data in "Firestore", I want to get all documents according to "city" like all users who have city "karachi" and stored in `arrayList` of type "chatModel" I want to show this data in recyclerView

Here is the image of dataabase:
[image: Here is the image of dataabase]

**I have tried this but it's only getting me the last document from collection.**

```
      firestore.collection("USERS")
        .whereEqualTo("city",cityName)
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            for (document in documents) {

                arrayList.add(document.toObject(chatModel::class.java))

                Log.i("Info", "${document.id} => ${document.data}")


            }

            val adapter = chatAdapter(context!!, arrayList)
            chatRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context,
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
            chatRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

**Here is the Logcat result:**

```
v21GH5sBi3SdIb3v3xsp3ob64S23 => {username=Muhammad Rizwan, Email=mr1017753@gmail.com, city=Karachi, ProfileImageUrl=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/me2wee-1b547.appspot.com/o/USERS-MEDIA%2Fv21GH5sBi3SdIb3v3xsp3ob64S23?alt=media&token=193c4013-c580-45dc-b63d-fee1ef13caba}
```

Here is the screenshot of all documents which contain the city "Karachi" but it's only getting the last one

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable problem with **lowercase** and **upper case**. You're problem might be similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50812056/10182897)

As I can see your described in database city value is `karachi` in **lowercase** but output you provided **uppercase** Result.

```
firestore.collection("USERS").get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
        for (document in documents) {
            if(document.get("city").equals("karachi") || document.get("city").equals("Karachi")){
                arrayList.add(document.toObject(chatModel::class.java));
            }
        }

        val adapter = chatAdapter(context!!, arrayList)
        chatRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
        chatRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried this but it's not working

It doesn't work because you are creating a `chatAdapter` object at every iteration of your for loop. To solve this, move the last four lines of code outside the loop. Inside the loop should exist only:

```
arrayList.add(document.toObject(chatModel::class.java))
```

In this way you populate the list and set the adapter only when the list is full of objects.

Comment: Actually , The porblem is i am not getting the data in arrayList. I want to know how i can retrive the data

Comment: If you try to log `Log.d(TAG, document.toObject(chatModel::class.java).city)`, what is printed out in the logcat?

Comment: it's only getting the last document from firestore

Comment: It should print each and every name. Have you tried to get those lines out of the loop?

Comment: Yes i have tried all these code out of loop but its only getting me a last document

Comment: Edit your question and add the exact code that you are using now.

Comment: I see, in that case your query is returning a single user since only one of them has set the city to `Karachi`,  right? That's the point, to return only with a specific city.

Comment: No , In my collection there are 3 documents with city "Karachi" but it's only getting the last document and this document is related to me as all the data stored in the document are mine

Comment: Please add a screenshot also with the other documents as well.

Comment: But it's the same with the first one `eDj7...`. Please add another one.